# Как изменить цвет, встроенного SVG изображения в формате base64

Tags: css, svg

В готовой библиотеке используется встроенное SVG изображение в формате:

```
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
```

Хотелось бы изменить цвета, используемые в изображении. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: при таком методе вставки картинки через css hue rotate или подменой исходника в рантайм

Comment: @StrangerintheQ: пока кодил, правильный коммент появился. Подмена - наше всё :)

Comment: а можно просто base64 вставить в url сохранить как index.svg и поменять fill и потом опять преобразовать в base64

Comment: @Tea Вы спросили, вам ответили. Хорошо бы выбрать ответ, который вам больше подходит. (галочка рядом с цифрой у ответа)

Answer (score 6):

Изменить цвет изображения в формате `base64` можно только с помощью фильтров CSS или SVG

Например: для вашего изображения:

```css
.rect {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA4MDAgODAwIj4NCjxnIGlkPSJicm93bi1ib2FyZCI+DQo8ZyBpZD0iTGlnaHQiIGZpbGw9IiNkZWUzZTYiPg0KPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjgwMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI4MDAiLz4NCjwvZz4NCjxnIGlkPSJGcmFtZSIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSI+DQo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iODAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgwMCIvPg0KPC9nPg0KPGcgaWQ9IkRhcmsiIGZpbGw9IiM4Y2EyYWQiPg0KPGcgaWQ9InJheiI+DQo8ZyBpZD0iZHZhIj4NCjxnIGlkPSJ0cmkiPg0KPHJlY3QgeD0iMTAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIvPg0KPHJlY3QgeD0iMzAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIvPg0KPHJlY3QgeD0iNTAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIvPg0KPHJlY3QgeD0iNzAwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIvPg0KPC9nPg0KPHVzZSB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSgtMTAwLDEwMCkiIHhsaW5rOmhyZWY9IiN0cmkiLz4NCjwvZz4NCjx1c2UgdHJhbnNmb3JtPSJ0cmFuc2xhdGUoMCwyMDApIiB4bGluazpocmVmPSIjZHZhIi8+DQo8L2c+DQo8dXNlIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAsNDAwKSIgeGxpbms6aHJlZj0iI3JheiIvPg0KPC9nPg0KPC9nPg0KPC9zdmc+'); 

}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Инвертировать цвет с помощью `filter: invert(100%);`

```css
.rect {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'); 
filter:invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Изменить цвет с помощью фильтра `filter: hue-rotate(180deg);`

```css
.rect {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'); 
filter: hue-rotate(250deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: Но тогда на всех потомков так же будет действовать фильтр. Если rect - не отдельный елемент для фона, с содержимым могут быть небольшие проблемы)

Comment: @ДавидМанжула может быть я не совсем точно понял ваш комментарий, но тут никаких потомков нет, какие могут быть потомки у background-image, картинки в формате base64

Comment: я про потомков `div.rect`

Comment: @Давид Манжула фильтры [не наследуются](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: https://codepen.io/da411d/full/rNObbRz

Comment: @ДавидМанжула то есть хотите сказать, что вы опровергли теорию? И фильтры наследуются? Вы применили фильтр к одному классу `rect` Покажите пример, где есть действительно родитель и потомок

Answer (score 6):

Этот метод может показатся слишком сложным или кардинальным, но на самом деле ничего сложного тут нет.

1. Берем base64-код картинки - то, что лежит после `base64,`

```
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
```

2. Декодируем base64 (могу посоветовать [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/)) (я так же отформатировал для понятности)

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
  <g id="brown-board">
    <g id="Light" fill="#dee3e6">
      <rect width="800" height="800"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Frame" fill="none">
      <rect width="800" height="800"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Dark" fill="#8ca2ad">
      <g id="raz">
        <g id="dva">
          <g id="tri">
            <rect x="100" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="300" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="500" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="700" width="100" height="100"/>
          </g>
          <use transform="translate(-100,100)" xlink:href="#tri"/>
        </g>
        <use transform="translate(0,200)" xlink:href="#dva"/>
      </g>
      <use transform="translate(0,400)" xlink:href="#raz"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

3. Меняем цвета

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
  <g id="brown-board">
    <g id="Light" fill="#ffc000">
      <rect width="800" height="800"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Frame" fill="none">
      <rect width="800" height="800"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Dark" fill="#000000">
      <g id="raz">
        <g id="dva">
          <g id="tri">
            <rect x="100" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="300" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="500" width="100" height="100"/>
            <rect x="700" width="100" height="100"/>
          </g>
          <use transform="translate(-100,100)" xlink:href="#tri"/>
        </g>
        <use transform="translate(0,200)" xlink:href="#dva"/>
      </g>
      <use transform="translate(0,400)" xlink:href="#raz"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

4. Кодируем в base64

```
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
```

5. Возвращаем на место

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
```

Теперь можем задать его нужному елементу:

```
.some-element{
  background-image: url('...');
}
```

Главное - чтоб наш стиль находился в коде ниже оригинального, тогда он переопределит старый. Ну или `!important`. Или заменить в исходном коде, если есть доступ.

Вот пример того что у меня получилось:

```css
.rect {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

---

`base64` - это просто способ кодирования непечатных символов в последовательность символов из диапазона `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `/`, `+`, `=`. Никакой магии тут нет. Просто SVG - это XML-формат картинок, который можно редакртировать прямо в текстовом редакторе. С PNG-иконками будет сложнее, но справится все равно можно.

Если вам нужно отредактировать PNG-иконку, просто вставьте `data:image/png;base64,...` в адресную строку браузера и нажмите Enter. Изображение откроется как самая обычная картинка. Теперь можете нажать Ctrl-S чтоб сохранить картинку и отредактировать ее. Далее, чтоб снова получить base64, советую использовать онлайн-инструменты, например, [base64-image.de](https://www.base64-image.de/) (это можно сделать и штатными средствами, но там чуточку сложнее).
Так же, чтоб уменьшить вес картинки, советую использовать сервисы типа [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/)

Comment: `btoa()` и `atob()`

Comment: это правильный метод

Answer (score 6):

"Костыль" для смены цвета "на лету":

```js
function fChangeColor() {
  let oDivSvg = document.querySelector('div.svg'),
    sBgImage = window.getComputedStyle(oDivSvg).backgroundImage,
    sLightVal = +document.querySelector('input.light').value + 10,
    sDarkVal = +document.querySelector('input.dark').value + 170;

  let sDecodedData = window.atob(sBgImage.replace(/^.+?,(.+)"\)$/gim, '$1'));

  let sModData = sDecodedData
    .replace(/(id="Light" fill=").+?"/gim, `$1hsl(${sLightVal},100%,50%)"`)
    .replace(/(id="Dark" fill=").+?"/gim, `$1hsl(${sDarkVal},100%,50%)"`);

  oDivSvg.style.backgroundImage = `url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(sModData)}')`;
  oDivSvg.innerText = sModData;
}
```

```css
div.svg {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  font: bold 13px monospace; color: white; text-shadow: 0 0 5px black, 0 0 2px black, 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="light" oninput="fChangeColor()"><input type="range" class="dark" oninput="fChangeColor()">
<div class="svg"></div>
```

Comment: почему костыль? Вполне законный, классный ответ

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: законный корявый костыль. Ходить помогает, но лучше на своих "двоих" твёрдо держаться :) В общем, не надо так делать часто. Только когда совсем "no escape".

Comment: @UModeL, да, для продакшина не пойдет, но для какого-то генератора-конструктора будет удобно, особенно если заказчик хочет менять часто

Comment: @ДавидМанжула: всё верно. Это просто пища для ума. Ну и если внимательно разобраться, то кучу всего можно узнать/усвоить/закрепить.

Comment: @UModeL и я об этом же хотел сказать, что это почти готовая утилита для смены цвета картинки в формате base64. Только добавить вывод в консоль готового результата